# "As such" vs. "When used in such a way"

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, phrase-choice, sentence-choice

> - In the following example, "." is used to delimit the fractional part of the number from its whole part. **As such**, it is called a *decimal point*, not a *period*.
> - In the following example, "." is used to delimit the fractional part of the number from its whole part. **When used in this way**, it is called a *decimal point*, not a *period*.

Is it correct to use "as such" in sentences like the one above? I have tried to find authoritative examples on the Internet, but for some reason the texts that contain such sentences are written by authors who have some relation to Korea, and so it makes me think that native speakers would prefer the second version. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"As such..." means "Because of this it is called a decimal point, not a period."

"When used in this way..." means that it is called a decimal point only when it is used the way it is being used in this case.

"When used in this way" means that it is not always called a decimal point. "As such" means that it is always called a decimal point.

In this context "When used in this way" is best because it is only called a decimal point when it is in a number. It wouldn't be too unnatural to use "As such" here, but it would be slightly ambiguous.

TLDR: You are right, "when used in this way" is best.